# Whats the equivalent of RDD aggregateByKey for Spark dataframe using scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, rdd, apache-spark-ml

I wrote my below code to calculate the correlation for a dataframe using grouping but I eventually had to use RDD AggregateByKey, Sequential Operation and Combiner operation to achieve what I needed. However, I want to implement the same using only spark dataframe and avoid RDD completely.  I tried learning about Spark dataframe and I came across "agg" and "Group by" function but wasn't exactly sure how to achieve the same results as using the RDD. Any help here is much appreciated?

```
      val columnIndexes = columns.indices.map(i => i + groupIndexes.length).toArray
      //removing rows with nulls in group by columns like the MR version
      val cleanDF = selectedDF.na.drop("any", groupByColumns)

      val allCountersPerGroupRDD: RDD[(immutable.IndexedSeq[Any], Seq[Seq[CovCounter]])] = cleanDF.rdd.map(row =>
        //create key value pairs
        (groupIndexes.map(ind => row.get(ind)), columnIndexes.map(i => toDouble(row.get(i)))))
        .aggregateByKey(zeroCounters, numPartitions)(
          seqOp = (counters, newValues) => {
            for ((i, j) <- columnHalfPairedIndicesFlattened) {
              counters(i)(j).addIfNotNaN(newValues(i), newValues(j))
            }
            counters
          }, combOp = (baseCounters, otherCounters) => {
            for ((i, j) <- columnHalfPairedIndicesFlattened) {
              baseCounters(i)(j).merge(otherCounters(i)(j))
            }
            baseCounters
          })

  
      val finalRDD: RDD[Row] = allCountersPerGroupRDD.mapPartitions { iterator =>
        iterator.flatMap { case (groupKeys, counts) =>
          columns.indices.map(ind =>
            Row.fromSeq(groupKeys ++ Seq(columns(ind)) ++ columnPairedIndicesAll(ind).map { case (i, j) =>
              getCovOrCorrFromCounters(i, j, counts, useCorrelation)
            }))
        }
      }
      val outDF = sparkSession.createDataFrame(finalRDD, outputSchema)
```

Comment: So, you do not agree with the answer? It is the accepted df equivalent.

Comment: @thebluephantom I tried applying it but couldn't get the desired results. Anyway thanks for the pointer.

Answer (score 0):

See https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/udaf-scala.html. You need to make your own UDAF.